# Check in/Check out system QR codes

Tags: wordpress, civimember, civivolunteer, civihr

I have been searching if anyone has described how to achieve something similar to what we would like to do: We currently use a manual sign in sheet for our members (use of this sheet is sadly not consistent). 
We are hoping to find a way to have our members scan a QR code themselves as they come through the door and to do the same on the way out while creating a record.

Ideally, it would also run a test to see if a specific membership is currently up to date and send a payment request to them if not(however this is not vital). Does anyone know of a group that has done something similar or can point us in the right direction?

thank you for your help,
best regards,
JD

Comment: have you checked out civimobile? https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/event-participants-management-in-the-new-version-of-civimobile

Answer (score 1):

The QR Code Checkin Extension does (some of) that:  https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin ?